How do devs use shielded transactions in TRON?
I can't seem to understand how as a developer I should interact with ShieldedTRC20. Specifically how to generate arguments and zk proofs for minting etc.
Official docs are pointing to use Wallet API but it doesn't seem safe to ask some 3rd party for your keys and proofs. Is the only way to run locally full-blown node and wallet just to create zk proofs and z-addresses?
